# Splitting Excel 2007 in task bar

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2007

I wish to view 2 Excel 2007 files in 2 different Excel windows,
although there are 2 "Excels" in the task bar, they both points to the same app.
how can I make it split (like word)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Launch Excel twice (quickest way is pressing the Windows logo and typing Excel)

Open each Excel file in a seperate instance of Excel, you can now order them side by side if you like or move them to another monitor.

To get them side by side nicely, press Windows + Left/Right arrow to have it stick to either half of the screen.

Comment: :-) ha... I can't believe it is as that simple.
IS there a way to split a current excel app (with 3 windows) into a new instance ?

Comment: You might be able to drag the workbooks between different Excel instances

Comment: Hard to believe that you have to do this in such a roundabout way... it shouldn't be this difficult and counter-intuitive. Thanks Ivo :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Excel that controls the appearance of Excel on the taskbar. You can read about it [here](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T003028_Appearance_of_Excel_on_the_Taskbar.html). You may also want to turn off Direct Data Exchange so Excel launches in separate instances.

Comment: The task bar appearance is OK. the problem was that opening a new document from the same instance prevents me from putting them side by side in difference excel instances. I will check that DDE feature.

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer to keep the files in the same instance of excel. There are a number of features that don't work between files if you open in different instances (as in Ivo's answer). Another way to accomplish this is to open the 2 files in the same excel window, then go to View > Arrange All, then select Vertical and press OK. Same excel window, but can now view 2 files at once.

You can even view 2 sheets of the same file this way. The only difference is that first you must select View > New Window.

There are times where I use Ivo's method. Mainly when I have files with macros that I need to test or compare to other versions. I find it best to separate the instances and processes.